# Configure EC2 to allow internal and external DNS lookups

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53

Im a little new to AWS, but I've been a Linux admin/engineer for a while. I had a question regarding AWS DNS setup.

I setup a Hosted Zone inside Route53 so I could configure the servers to use hostnames without having to tweak the */etc/hosts* file for every record. I went into the VPC and created the DHCP Option Sets and set the domain I set in the Route 53 Hosted Zone, as well as the nameservers listed there.

That allows me to do the lookups to the servers on my domain, but obviously since I removed the default Nameserver from the DHCP Option Sets, it cant do external lookups.

If I create a Option Set with the default Nameserver, and then the rest from ones assigned to the Domain, that wont work either, it just uses whatever teh first NS entry is in the *resolv.conf* (which I expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set the DNS up so any lookups to *.mydomain.aws will use
>   NameServers I specify, and everything else will use the default one?

That's not how DNS works. You specify a set of DNS servers, your clients throw their requests at them, and the servers have to deal with whether or not they can get answers to the clients' queries.

Fortunately, with AWS, [Private Route53 Zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) are available. To use them, you'll need to configure your VPC hosts to use the amazon-provided DNS resolvers. More details on configuration are available in the linked documentation.

Comment: Perfect! I didnt mean to state it like I did, I apologize. I just meant that I needed to have it lookup internal and external records. Thanks for the help

Comment: Justin, glad to see this helped get you your answer! The odd misstatement will happen when you post on the SE network, especially when wading into a new but related area to something you already know - you're thinking about the issue based on your experience with what you know, and I've found for my own posts that I need a little time to learn to "think" in the terms each community already has mastered.  Feel free to edit your question to improve them as you get feedback.  Other people may do that FOR you just to help others find the questions in their searches.  But you can do so as well.